# How to receive textbox value from a Windows Toast Notificiation in a desktop app?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, windows-10, desktop-application

I'm writing a Windows 10 Desktop application in C# (not universal app, this is important) that needs to send a toast notification, which includes a textbox and a submit button.

I use [ToastNotification.Activated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.activated.aspx) to listen to when the submit button is clicked, but I can't find any way to extract the textbox text from the toast.

All the methods I've found - including MSFT article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/) and the StackOverflow answers given [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/), seem to apply to universal apps only, and I couldn't apply them to a desktop app.

Any clue on how to extract the textbox text input from a toast on a Win10 **desktop** app?

Attaching my code snippet below

Thanks

```
   private void ShowToastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string toastXmlString=$@"
    <toast action='submit'>
        <visual>
            <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                <text hint-maxLines='1'>Line1</text>
                <text>Line2</text>
            </binding>
        </visual>
        <actions>
            <input id='textBox' type='text' placeHolderContent='text' />
            <action
                content='Submit'
                hint-inputId='textBox'
                arguments='action=text' />
        </actions>
    </toast>";

        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastCustomtXml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        toastCustomtXml.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

        // Create the toast and attach event listeners
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastCustomtXml);
        toast.Activated += ToastActivated;
        toast.Dismissed += ToastDismissed;
        toast.Failed += ToastFailed;

        // Show the toast. Be sure to specify the AppUserModelId on your application's shortcut!
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(APP_ID).Show(toast);
    }

    private void ToastActivated(ToastNotification sender, object e)
    {
        // This event is fired, but I can't extract the textbox text
        // 'e' is a ToastActivatedEventArgs object, e.Arguments == 'action=text'

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Activate();
            Output.Text = "The user activated the toast.";
        });
    }
```

Comment: What desktop app you mean here? Just create a uwp app and target desktop?

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT My app isn't a UWP app, it's a standard C# desktop program. I can't switch to UWP app because it is very restrictive and some of my features won't work.

Comment: Hi, I know that it is an old post, but have you found any solution for this ? I have the same problem and I'm searching for solution. I could be so glad for any useful advice.

Comment: @bensvk nope, I ended up writing a special UWP app just for that, which communicated with my main app (non-uwp). Completely ridiculous. I've been out of the desktop apps playground for a while though, so things might have changes since.

Answer (score -1):

In your App.xaml.cs file add an override void to handle OnActivated.

```
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle toast activation
    if (e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
    {
         var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

         string text = toastActivationArgs.UserInput.Values.ToList()[0].ToString());
              
     }
     Window.Current.Activate();
}
```